# what is this scala grammar

Tags: scala, grammar

what is this grammar? What function was called?
Does this grammar have a name?

```scala
val indataRDD = sc.makeRDD(Array("1,jack,15","2,Lily,16","3,mike,16"))

val rdd = indataRDD.map( _.split(',') ).map{
  arr => {
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(arr(0)))
    put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes(arr(1)))
    put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("age"),Bytes.toBytes(arr(2).toInt))

    ***(new ImmutableBytesWritable, put)***
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to ask exactly it’s just an object creation nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

This is syntax sugar to create a tuple of two elements.
The line `(new ImmutableBytesWritable, put)` is therefore equivalent to `new Tuple2(new ImmutableBytesWritable, put)`